# Horizontally centering two stacked divs, when one has a vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, centering

Centering elements horizontally is easy using `margin: 0 auto;`

However, it doesn't work if there are two elements stacked in a column and one has a scrollbar and the other does not. In that case, the two horizontal centered elements aren't aligned anymore.

**Question**: Is there any way to align the two elements without using Javascript to adjust the margin of the first one?

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/904umrhy/4/)

```
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0; height: 100vh;
    }

    .header {
      height: 50px; background: red;
    }

    .content {
      overflow-y: scroll; background: blue;
    }

    .inner {
      background: rgba(255,255,255,.5); max-width: 300px;
      margin: 0 auto; min-height: 50px;
    }

    .content > .inner {
      min-height: 300px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: DEMO]

Comment: Why not just do it like this? https://jsfiddle.net/904umrhy/2/

Comment: Scrollbar widths are OS / browser dependent, so your solution works for your browser, but [doesn't correctly align for me](http://i.imgur.com/wvuKxSc.png). It's even more an issue for OS X users, because scrollbars are overlays there.

Comment: So why not use Javascript then? You don't need full JQuery libraries, just simple javascript.

Comment: Javascript is just a workaround, no solution. It's the last thing I want to use, before I'd switch to a fixed header probably. As pointed out by Wes in chat, it's entirely possible with CSS only. I posted it as answer, because he's too lazy.

Comment: Considering your answer is not centered, I feel that your answer is also no a solution, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/904umrhy/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Answer from Wes in chat**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30181868#30181868):

This can be solved by adding a scrollbar to the first one, but hiding it from the user.

```
.header {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 120%;
  margin-left: -10%;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/904umrhy/1/)

If you're concerned a user could have a scrollbar wider than 10%, increase it `width: 300%` and `margin-left: -100%`. If somebody has a scrollbar as wide as the page, he / she can't use the page anyway.

Comment: This is not centered see example. https://jsfiddle.net/904umrhy/5/ its aligned but not centered.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith It's not centered to the viewport, but the lower white box is centered in its parent and the other upper white box is correctly aligned.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is obviously the centering. So why not circumvent it and use `margin-left`?

Try this CSS:

```
.inner { margin-left: calc(50vw - 150px); }  /* half viewport width less half element width 
                                                (for precise centering) */
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  background: blue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inner {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  max-width: 300px;
  /* margin: 0 auto;                   <-- remove */
  margin-left: calc(50vw - 150px);     /* new */
  min-height: 50px;
}

.content > .inner {
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

### [**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/904umrhy/6/)